# IOS Remove CCLayer and Replace With ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, storyboard

I'm going to preface this question with the fact that I'm a complete novice in IOS, and I'm trying to learn as I go here.

The app I'm working on has a single Navigation Controller containing a Title Screen View Controller containing the app options. When I click the start button in the Title Screen it takes me to the Main Game Screen View Controller which has a CCLayer for doing some simple Cocos2D animation. All of this is working very well. Here's what I'm missing. I'm trying to programmatically go back to the title screen. I'm thinking there might be 2 options

1 - End the CCLayer somehow which will return me back to the Main Game View Controller where I can then send a command to go to the Title View Controller?

2 - Get a reference to the parent view controller of the CCLayer, and do the same as above.

I've scoured the internet for a couple of days trying to find what to do, and I'm out of ideas. I don't really have anything to show apart from I think I need to initialize the Title View Controller again.

Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as you mentioned, you have a navigation controller which means that your Main Game View controller is pushed over your Title View Controller.

and your CCLayer is added on MainGameView Controller

so all you ever need to do is to pop your MainGameViewController. that shall automatically take you to your titleViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write in your acton method

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];
```

You will be in previous scene.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this answer pointed me in the right direction.